# "adb devices" command returns no devices

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, windows-7

I am just getting started in Android development, and am trying to get Eclipse (running on Windows 7) to recognise my phone so that I can use it for debugging. However, my phone does not seem to be recongised by Eclipse or by running "adb devices" from a command line.

Here's what I've tried:

- I've tried both MTP (media device) and PTP (camera) transfer modes (similar questions on Stack Overflow have been resolved by using PTP).
- I've ensured that USB debugging is turned on in my phone's settings.
- I've manually installed a driver in Device Manager, by choosing "Update Driver Software" and selecting the .inf file in sdk\extras\google\usb_driver (which I had to modify by hand to include my device).
- I've tried a Nexus 4 phone, a Nexus 7 tablet, and a Motorola Moto G phone. Behaviour is identical for all three devices.
- I've tried the "Universal ADB driver", in case it behaves differently to the Google driver, but it doesn't behave any differently.
- I've rebooted, I've reinstalled drivers, I've tried adb kill-server followed by adb start-server, etc.

No matter what combinations of the above I try, "adb devices" lists nothing. When I look in the Windows Device Manager, I can see "Android Composite ADB Interface" listed under the "Android Device" node, so I believe I have installed the driver correctly. I am logged in as an Administrator, so it's not a permissions thing either. I've tried every answer to every single similar question on Stack Overflow, but nothing works. I've been pulling my hair out all day and am close to running out of hair... any ideas appreciated.

EDIT: It just occurred to me what could be causing this. I am running 64-bit Windows 7, but 32-bit Java. Because I have 32-bit Java installed on my PC, I installed the 32-bit SDK. Would that explain this behaviour? Should I be running 64-bit Java? The only reason why I didn't is because 32-bit Java is installed by my company's group policy...

**EDIT2: I have now noticed that when I plug an Android device in, and look at its Device ID in Device Manager, the device ID does not end in "&MI_01". When I plug the device into another Windows 7 PC, the device ID *does* end in "&MI_01". I believe this is why "adb devices" is not able to detect the device. Any idea why one PC would see a different device ID to another, with the only difference being the "&MI_01"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer. I was missing a file called usb.inf from C:\Windows\inf. Not sure how on earth files just go missing from yours Windows directory...

Answer (score 0):

Did you install your phone **USB-driver**?
and can you check it on device manager is installed or not? you can download your usb driver from yur phone company website.
After you install your phone usb driver , I think the problem is solved

Comment: Is that a question or an answer?

Comment: Hi Ersin, yes I've installed the driver from the phone company's website. That works fine until I enable "USB debugging" on the phone, at which point Device Manager doesn't like it, so the commonly accepted wisdom on Stack Overflow is to manually install the Google driver that's part of the SDK. That's why my Device Manager now lists "Android Composite ADB Interface."

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason is because the computer does not recognize your phone as below 1 device used to debug code, even usb device.
You can try to do the following:
- Turn up the window update
- Uninstall driver for usb connection from your phone to your computer
- Go to the homepage of the mobile device, download driver for usb connection to the computer and then reinstall the driver

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've tried installing multiple times the driver from the manufacturer's web site, to no avail. For debugging you need an ADB driver anyway, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try **Universal Naked Driver**. This is to allow ADB, Fastboot & APX interfaces to work without installing any package much less multiples packages for users with multiple devices.

[Download](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2372977&d=1383666308)

After downloading extract `.rar` file into a folder.

Go to Device Manager, right click on Android phone and click to update driver. On next screen , give path of extracted folder and install it.

You can install with `msi` file also. [Download .msi](http://hexamob.com/drivers/GENERICOS/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi)

Comment: I don't think the driver will make a difference - please see my second edit. Until I get the right Device ID appearing in Device Manager, ADB will never be able to see my device...